# Motion move sprite from point to point diagonally

Tags: java, geometry

So I am working on a blackjack game, I have wrote a render process which will render a card going out of the cards stack and sliding to the place where it shows all dealer's cards.

My method works fine, except one problem which I will elaborate:

Whenever Y coordinate reaches the target Y coordinate first, the sprite will only move on X-asis because it cant move Y anymore, instead of making a straight angle to the point.

So what it will do is move up diagonally and then instantly go to the right (in my case)

GIF:

[image: IMG]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/bec6daadcb46bedc4777a3e4c5ff8c77.gif))</sub>

MP4 (choose mp4 in the (..) menu http://gyazo.com/bec6daadcb46bedc4777a3e4c5ff8c77)

As you can see, it does what I just said.

What did I do wrong? how can I make it motion in a straight angle to the target without going diagonal up and than turn right away?

My process code:

```
    // If the target is on the right side of the start point
    if (startPoint.getX() < endPoint.getX()) {
        if (current.getX() < endPoint.getX()) {
            current.x += moveSpeed;
            if (current.getX() > endPoint.getX()) {
                current.x = (int) endPoint.getX();
            }
        }
        else {
            xDone = true;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (current.getX() > endPoint.getX()) {
            current.x -= moveSpeed;
            if (current.getX() < endPoint.getX()) {
                current.x = (int) endPoint.getX();
            }
        }
        else {
            xDone = true;
        }
    }

    // Vise-versa
    if (startPoint.getY() < endPoint.getY()) {
        if (current.getY() < endPoint.getY()) {
            current.y += moveSpeed;
            if (current.getY() > endPoint.getY()) {
                current.y = (int) endPoint.getY();
            }
        }
        else {
            yDone = true;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (current.getY() > endPoint.getY()) {
            current.y -= moveSpeed;
            if (current.getY() < endPoint.getY()) {
                current.y = (int) endPoint.getY();
            }
        }
        else {
            yDone = true;
        }
    }

    // Callback, dw about it
    CardContainer.getCardSprite(CardContainer.SPECIAL, 0).drawSprite((int) current.getX(), (int) current.getY());

    // Alert finished, in poisiuton
    if (xDone && yDone) {
        ch.submitCard(card);
    }
```

`current` = current position

`startPoint` = the start point

`endPoint` = the end point

Thanks!

EDited code:

```
private void applyMovement(double alpha) {
    double dx = endPoint.getX() - startPoint.getX();
    double dy = endPoint.getY() - startPoint.getY();

    this.current.setLocation(startPoint.getX() + alpha * dx, startPoint.getY() + alpha * dy);
}

public void process() {

    double alpha = (double) stepsDone / distance;
    applyMovement(alpha);
    stepsDone++;

    // Callback, dw about it
    CardContainer.getCardSprite(CardContainer.SPECIAL, 0).drawSprite((int) current.getX(), (int) current.getY());

    // Alert finished, in poisiuton
    if (stepsDone >= distance) {
        ch.submitCard(card);
    }
}
```

Distance calculation:

```
 this.distance = (int) start.distance(end);
```

Used Point2D distance method:

```
public double distance(Point2D pt) {
    double px = pt.getX() - this.getX();
    double py = pt.getY() - this.getY();
    return Math.sqrt(px * px + py * py);
}
```

Comment: You need separate X and Y moveSpeed's. You will probably also need to use floating point values for the speed and X/Y co-ordinates to get the required precision, and just cast back to int's to do the drawing.

Comment: It's hard to tell from the code that you posted. But you'll at least need two different `moveSpeed`s, one for x and one for y (and it should be a `double` variable, no `int`). Imagine you have to move 120 in x-direction and 100 in y-direction, then you may make 100 steps, with `moveSpeedX=1.2` and `moveSpeedY=1.0`.

Comment: @Marco13 Why 1.2? I assume you did 120 / 100 to get 1.2, but why? is it because y = 100 so x / y = 1.2?

Comment: It can be computed via `distanceX/numberOfSteps` and `distanceY/numberOfSteps`. BTW: I'd NOT recommend you to use a line equation for this, because the *slope* will tend to infinity when the distance in x-direction approaches zero!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to **not** use any form of "slope" in such a computation. You will run into problems when the difference in x-direction approaches zero, because then the *slope* will tend towards infinity.

Assuming that your points are `Point2D.Double` (or something similar - you should include this kind of information in your questions!), you can compute the movement as follows:

```
private Point2D.Double initial = ... // The initial position
private Point2D.Double current = ... // The current position
private Point2D.Double target = ... // The target position

void applyMovment(double alpha) {
    double dx = target.getX() - initial.getX();
    double dy = target.getY() - initial.getY();
    current.x = initial.getX() + alpha * dx;
    current.y = initial.getY() + alpha * dy;
}
```

The `applyMovment` method sketched here can be called with a `double` value between `0.0` and `1.0`, where `0.0` corresponds to the initial position and `1.0` corresponds to the target position. This is just a [Linear Interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation).

So for example, when you have some sort of loop for the animation, you can use the method as follows:

```
int numberOfSteps = 10;
for (int i=0; i<=numberOfSteps; i++)
{
    double alpha = (double)i / numberOfSteps;
    applyMovement(alpha);
    repaint();
}
```

This works for any arrangement of the start- and end points, without any sign- or direction issues. It just interpolates between the two positions.

Comment: This works, but when the card goes to the end, it starts to go very slowly before it reaches the point see here http://gyazo.com/ee2aca46341395924eeebb29d77c71f7, why is it happening? I edited my code.

Comment: Are you sure that `startPoint` and `current` are **different instances**, and **not** the same instance?

Comment: Yeah you caught me there. It's working now but very slowly, is there a way to increase the speed of the movement without ruining the balance?

Comment: Nevermind, I found out. I made it loop through i-0 to moveSpeed to applyMovement before render.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation needs to be based upon moving the `currentY` and `currentX` along a specific *line*, not a specific set of intervals (`moveSpeed`). The formula for graphing points on a line is:

```
y = mx + b
```

Where `x` and `y` are the varying points, `m` is equal to the **slope** of the line, and `b` is what's called the **y-intercept**.

Your **slope** is calculated by the formula:

```
double slope = ((double) endPoint.getY() - startPoint.getY()) / ((double) endPoint.getX() - startPoint.getX());
```

And the Y intercept can be calculated by just plugging in a bunch of known values once you have them:

```
double yIntercept = (double) endPoint.getY() - (slope * endPoint.getX())
```

Then, just loop through the count of the difference in X:

```
for (int xVal = startPoint.getX(); xVal < endPoint.getX(); xVal++){
    currentX = xVal;
    currentY = (slope * xVal) + yIntercept;
}
```

And you should be good.

Warning: this is all off of the top of my head, I don't know if it'll compile.

Comment: Question: you do the for loop inside the rendering method? or its loop cycle per render cycle?

Comment: That loop will cover the entire render. If you want to do it seperately for each render cycle, you don't need the loop.

Comment: I still need to check in which direction the target is at though right (the if statements i have)?

Comment: More or less. My solution assumes that startX < endX and startY < endY. You'll need to make adjustments if that isn't the case.